# Are links to commercial training sources allowed?

Tags: discussion, answers, external-links

Is it acceptable to provide a link to an off-site resource if that resource requires a fee?

For example, can one say something like "... for more details, check out this Pluralsight course"  or "refer to chapter 5 in this book available on Amazon..."?

If not in an answer, would it be acceptable in comments?

I understand already that link-only answers are unacceptable.  This would be in addition to a fully qualified answer.

What if I am the author of that course or book?

While I understand that StackOverflow is not intended to be a place to advertise - if the material is directly relevant to the question asked, then is it acceptable?  Or is it not ever acceptable?

Comment: There's a difference between "for more details, check out XYZ" vs "I found XYZ useful".  Don't claim exclusivity unless you can back it up.

Comment: And you MUST disclose what your connection with the off-site resource is (should be done for non-commercial links also, but absolutely necessary regarding for-profit)

Comment: I came here because I was looking for a discussion on the [pluralsight] tag. 19 questions use it right now, but I think it shouldn't even be a valid tag. It feels like guerrilla marketing to me. I will edit out those tags myself, but what's the convention for pointing out an invalid tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When we moderate such links, we look for certain patterns:

1. Is the answer completely self-contained, or does it require clicking on the link to get the full answer?  Is the link relevant to the question?  Does it act as a supplement to an already good answer, or is it clearly just an advertisement?
2. Does the answerer exhibit some pattern of behavior that is consistent with a spammer?  Do they always include product links, regardless of their specific relevance to the question?  Do they copy/paste the same answer including their link across several similar or duplicate questions?

Paywalls don't necessarily disqualify supplementary links, but they do effectively prevent the community from evaluating the material at the provided link for its relevance (since we can't reasonably expect everyone to buy the book or article just to see if it applies to the question).

Consequently, I would only consider a link to such a book, article or course material completely legitimate *if the author freely offered the material that is relevant to the question in the answer itself.*

For example:

> For more information about this issue, you can read chapter 4 of **"Foo, Bar and Baz, a history of computing inflectives,**" which states that: *"Although 'performant' is not yet a real word in the Merriam Webster sense, it is widely used in the computing community as a synonym for 'high-performing' or 'adequately performing.'"*